# Building issue Mailcore2 library for Android

Tags: android, android-library, mailcore2

I use MailCore2 for a mail Android App. I followed the build instructions provided in the documentation (https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/tree/master/build-android).

```
$ export ANDROID_SDK=/path/to/android-sdk
$ export ANDROID_NDK=/path/to/android-ndk
$ cd build-android
$ ./build.sh
```

I get these messages:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:80 (message):
  ERROR: Could not find ctemplate


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
cp: /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/cmake-build/src/include/MailCore: No such file or directory
Android NDK: WARNING:/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/Android.mk:MailCore: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lc++_shared    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: MailCore <= com_libmailcore_AbstractMessage.cpp
In file included from /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/../../src/java/TypesUtils.h:7:0,
                 from /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/../../src/java/native/com_libmailcore_AbstractMessage.cpp:3:
/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/../../src/core/basetypes/MCBaseTypes.h:5:40: fatal error: MailCore/MCAutoreleasePool.h: No such file or directory
 #include <MailCore/MCAutoreleasePool.h>
                                        ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/obj/local/armeabi/objs/MailCore//Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/__/__/src/java/native/com_libmailcore_AbstractMessage.o] Error 1
cp: /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/libs/armeabi/libMailCore.so: No such file or directory
Android NDK: WARNING:/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/Android.mk:MailCore: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lc++_shared    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: MailCore <= com_libmailcore_AbstractMessage.cpp
In file included from /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/../../src/java/TypesUtils.h:7:0,
                 from /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/../../src/java/native/com_libmailcore_AbstractMessage.cpp:3:
/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/../../src/core/basetypes/MCBaseTypes.h:5:40: fatal error: MailCore/MCAutoreleasePool.h: No such file or directory
 #include <MailCore/MCAutoreleasePool.h>
                                        ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/MailCore//Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/__/__/src/java/native/com_libmailcore_AbstractMessage.o] Error 1
cp: /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/libs/armeabi-v7a/libMailCore.so: No such file or directory
Android NDK: WARNING:/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/Android.mk:MailCore: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lc++_shared    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[x86] Compile++      : MailCore <= com_libmailcore_AbstractMessage.cpp
In file included from /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/../../src/java/TypesUtils.h:7:0,
                 from /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/../../src/java/native/com_libmailcore_AbstractMessage.cpp:3:
/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/../../src/core/basetypes/MCBaseTypes.h:5:40: fatal error: MailCore/MCAutoreleasePool.h: No such file or directory
 #include <MailCore/MCAutoreleasePool.h>
                                        ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/obj/local/x86/objs/MailCore//Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/__/__/src/java/native/com_libmailcore_AbstractMessage.o] Error 1
cp: /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/libs/x86/libMailCore.so: No such file or directory
Android NDK: WARNING:/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/Android.mk:MailCore: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lc++_shared    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[x86_64] Compile++      : MailCore <= com_libmailcore_AbstractMessage.cpp
In file included from /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/../../src/java/TypesUtils.h:7:0,
                 from /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/../../src/java/native/com_libmailcore_AbstractMessage.cpp:3:
/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/../../src/core/basetypes/MCBaseTypes.h:5:40: fatal error: MailCore/MCAutoreleasePool.h: No such file or directory
 #include <MailCore/MCAutoreleasePool.h>
                                        ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/obj/local/x86_64/objs/MailCore//Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/jni/__/__/src/java/native/com_libmailcore_AbstractMessage.o] Error 1
cp: /Users/thee/AndroidStudioProjects/JavaMailApp/libs/mailcore2-master/build-android/libs/x86_64/libMailCore.so: No such file or directory
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning
```

It produces the binary `mailcore2-android-version.aar` as stated in the docs, but I can't use it in my project. It crashes each time I try to use functions of mailcore library.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You have to get ctemplate: "ERROR: Could not find ctemplate"

Comment: Yes and I can't find where it is coming from. I searched for a long time but no one seems to have a similar issue. I don't know what ctemplate is and what it is used for. So it would be great if someone could give me a lead on this particular error...

Answer (score 4):

A bit late but may be useful for future users :

Create a 'MailCore' directory in `build-android/includes`.
Then from the `src/` directory, execute (for OS X) :

```
cp `find . -name '*.h'`  ../build-android/includes/MailCore/
```

It worked for me!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I had to copy all the header files into the "include" folder, not "includes". Then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If this is on Mac OS X, you can download the missing component *CTemplate* ([here](https://code.google.com/p/rudix/wiki/ctemplate)) and *Libetpan* ( [here](http://www.etpan.org/libetpan.html) ; if that error pops up later). Installing these components resolved these errors for me.